# Find location from tweet ID

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, geocoding

I have a list of tweets. For each tweet I have different attributes (user, date, text and tweet IDs).

[image: Tweet export]

To scrape that data, I’m using the project of Jefferson Henrique (https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python).

In addition to that, I would like to know two geographical elements for each tweet:

1. where tweets were generated (location or long, lat)?
2. where the user resides?

Do you have any idea to get those two information either from tweet IDs or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to post the json file of the tweet to let me locate where the information is.

From my experience, the location of the tweet may not always be available, depending on whether the user allows location sharing when tweeting.

For the user location, it is usually not in the tweet. Scrape the user profile and you should easily find it.

Comment: I put an extract of my tweet export in the first post.

Comment: According to the document of what you are using, after you have a tweet object returned, use tweet.geo

Comment: just like you use tweet.text for text, use tweet.geo for location

Answer (score 0):

You could query the Twitter API directly using the tweet id.  This would allow you to retrieve more data about the tweet, including the location if available.

According to the [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json#fundamentals):

> If the Tweet is geo-tagged, there will a "place" object included.